# Angularjs, function not being properly invoked inside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm doing this login exercise where users can login and post notes, and view the notes that they've posted. My problem is when I logout and login with a different user I see the notes from the previous user.

Here's an illustration:

[image: https://gyazo.com/ddeae869673926047fd205a8edeb150b]

I log in with a different user then this shows up:

[image: https://gyazo.com/0a1905b88b5148be171a44d8876304d5]

I restart the page and the appropriate note shows up:

[image: https://gyazo.com/dcd199a41738ecd2ac9a85fe5832e51a]

The controller for this:

```
exports.homeController = function ($scope, $location, $q, $users, $window, $notes, $http) {
  var auth = function () {
    var userInfo = $users.getUserInfo()

    if (userInfo) {
      return $q.when(userInfo)
    } else {
      return $q.reject({ authenticated: false })
    }
  }

  $scope.userInfo = auth()

  myNotes($scope.userInfo.$$state.value.accessToken) // I invoke my function to get the notes for each specific user but it doesn't seem to work.

  $scope.logout = function () {
    $users.logout()
      .then(function (results) {
        $scope.userInfo = null
        $scope.myNotes = null
        $location.path('/')
      }, function (err) {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }

  $scope.notes = {
    notes: ''
  }

  $scope.postNote = function () {
    $notes.postNotes($scope.userInfo.$$state.value.accessToken, $scope.notes)
      .then(function (result) {
        $scope.myNotes.push($scope.notes)
        $scope.notes = ''
      }, function (err) {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }

  function myNotes (user_id) {
    $notes.getMyNotes(user_id)
      .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result)
        $scope.myNotes = result.data
      }, function (err) {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }
}
```

This is the app https://login-sys.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Are you properly clearing your user info as part of your logout process?

It seems like `$scope.userInfo.$$state.value.accessToken` might be surviving the logout, meaning the previously logged in user's info is still being used until a hard refresh resets the state of the app.

Comment: You should try putting the `var deferred = $q.defer();` in the `getMyNotes` and `postNotes` methods, just before the `$http.get`. I think the problem is that you don't renew the promise and the second time the first request's promise is returned with the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found your non-minified code for the services.

Based on that I think the problem is that you declare `var deferred = $q.defer()` one time in the `$notes` service.

I think it should be "renewed" every time the service methods are called:

```
function getMyNotes (user_id) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('/api/myNotes/' + user_id + '?access_token=' + user_id)
        .then(function (result) {
            deferred.resolve(result)
        }, function (err) {
            deferred.reject(err)
        });
    return deferred.promise
}
```

Similarly in `postNotes`.

The second time you return the same promise with the same value, so your `homeController`'s `getMyNotes` function will get the same result despite the `$notes` service making a new request.

In the `$users` service's `logout` and `signup` functions you are already using it correctly.

Comment: Aweeessomme! Thank you for this. You don't know how much hair I've pulled out because of this problem.